# Git rollback a branch to a previous commit while keeping master branch where it's at (and PR that branch?)

Tags: git, github

I'm doing some contributing on an open source project on github. The repo owner said he would prefer separate PR's for the things I'm working on. However, I had already started working on the next issue on the master branch.

So I'd like to open up a new branch, roll back that branch to where the first issue was fixed, and push that branch as a PR.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

By rebasing... and I understand you are working on master?

```
# let's create the new branch
git branch second master # right where your master is right now
# now let's put master where you really want it to be now
git checkout master
# if you have stuff laying around, stash it before running the next command
git reset --hard revision-where-you-want-it
# now you can force-push master so your previous PR only holds this in

# rebasing second
git rebase --onto orign/master master second # move only revisions past master
```

And you are done.